# accessing json elements in dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to access json elements in dart

I tested out to see what the json format is. Initially it's this: (just a sample)

```
{
    "trails": [
        {
        "id": 7002454,
        "name": "Bidwell Park Tour",
        "location": "Chico, California",
        "longitude": -121.7919,
        "latitude": 39.7617,
        }
}
```

After fetching the data and decoding, I get a string of what's within the trails object. Then I encode it to get it back to json and I get this format:

```
      [{
        "id": 7002454,
        "name": "Bidwell Park Tour",
        "location": "Chico, California",
        "longitude": -121.7919,
        "latitude": 39.7617,
        }]
```

Here's my code of what I've tried so far:

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: trails.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
       //string representation of the json returned, commented out to avoid 
       //errors in multiple returns
      //return Text( trails[index].trails.toString());
        //encoded back to json (not sure if I'm assigning it into the right 
        //variable type
        Object myText  = json.encode(trails[index].trails);
        List<Map> myText2 = json.decode(myText);

        return Text(myText2[0]['name']);
```

The way I currently have it, it's returning:

```
     List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>.
```

I'm not sure what needs to change. I can post more code if anyone wants to see where I fetch the data. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `List<Map>` to `List<dynamic>`